# Websocket isn't connected to server in react-native

Tags: android, react-native, java-websocket

I am developing mobile app using react native. It includs websocket communication.
In debug mode, all is working well, but websocket isn't connected to server in release mode.
I use built-in library for websocket. Is there any person to have same problem?
Thanks for paying attention to my asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized this problem is dued to android permission problem.
I added `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` AndroidManifest.xml in release folder.

Then all is ok.